# Logstash grok filter custom pattern is not working

Tags: regex, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

I've a log file (http://codepad.org/vAMFhhR2), and I want to extract a specific number out of it (line 18)
I wrote a custom pattern grok filter, tested it on http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/, it works fine and extracts my desired value.

here's how logstash.conf looks like:

```
input {
    tcp {
        port => 5000
    }
}

filter {
    grok{
         match => [ "message", "(?<scraped>(?<='item_scraped_count': ).*(?=,))" ]
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
    }
}
```

but it doesn't match any record from the same log on Kibana

Thoughts?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this lookahead and lookbehind? Are you trying to discard the lines that don't match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regexp may be valid but the lookahead and lookbehind ("?=" and "?<=") are not a good choice in this context. Instead you could use a much simpler filter:

```
match => [ "message", "'item_scraped_count': %{NUMBER:scraped}" ]
```

This will extract the number after `'item_scraped_count':` as a field called `scraped`, using the 'NUMBER' Grok [built-in pattern](https://github.com/hpcugent/logstash-patterns/blob/master/files/grok-patterns).

Result in Kibana:

```
{
  "_index": "logstash-2017.04.11",
  "_type": "logs",
  "_source": {
    "@timestamp": "2017-04-11T20:02:13.194Z",
    "scraped": "22",
    (...)
  }
}
```

If I may suggest another improvement: since your message is spread across multiple lines you could easily merge it using the `multiline` input codec:

```
input {
    tcp {
        port => 5000
        codec => multiline {
            pattern => "^(\s|{')"
            what => "previous"
        }
    }
}
```

This will merge all the lines starting with either a whitespace or `{'` with the previous one.

Comment: That worked, thank you. from where can I gain more knowledge about coding logstash filters?

Comment: The official documentation is quite good, check the "Getting help" section: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html

Comment: Regarding the multiline filter, I added it but I expected finding all the logfile as a single message on Kibana, but it was split into 2 messages (http://codepad.org/gNGvbi4j), (http://codepad.org/qvRjg925)

Comment: That is not expected, it looks like there is a line break after "GET".